# How can I get value of an HTML element which is made by javascript using outerHTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a form that changes its elements using Javascript. I am getting HTML values in PHP by submitting the page. I am replacing an element by outerHTML. It is showing `Undefined index:(element's(made by javascript )` name). Can anyone please help me, I am a new student?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code that you are asking about in your question.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.